# PHP: preg_match; Not able to match the £ symbol

Tags: php, regex

I've really been wracking my brains over this one, as for the life of me I can't figure out what the problem is.

I've got some data I want to run a regular expression on. For reference, the original document is encoded in iso-8859-15, if that makes any difference.

Here is a function using the regular expression;

```
if(preg_match("{£\d+\.\d+}", $handle)) // 
{
    echo 'Found a match';

}
else
{
    echo 'No match found';
}
```

No matter what I try I can't seem to get it to match. I've tried just searching for the £ symbol. I've gone over my regular expression and there aren't any issues there. I've even pasted the source data directly into a regular expression tester and it finds a complete match for what I'm looking for. I just don't understand why my regular expression isn't working. I've looked at the raw data in my string that I'm searching for and the £ symbol is there as clear as day.

I get the feeling that there's some encoded character there that I just can't see, but no matter how I output the data all I can see is the £ symbol, but for whatever reason it's not being recognised.

Any ideas? Is there an absolute method to viewing raw data in a string? I've tried var_dump and var_export, but I do get the feeling that something isn't quite right, as var_export does display the data in a different language. How can I see what's "really" there in my variable?

I've even saved the content to a txt file. The £ is there. There should be no reason why I shouldn't be able to find it with my regular expression. I just don't get it. If I create a string and paste in the exact bit of test my regular expression should pick up, it finds the match without any problems.

Truly baffling.

Comment: how is your php file encoded?

Comment: Just for the record, the problem isn't with the delimeters, as those delimeters work. Just in case however, I tried several different delimeters, and it makes no difference.

Comment: I assume this is due to `preg_match` not being able to match multibyte characters, unless specifying the `u` modifier

Comment: `Is there an absolute method to viewing raw data in a string` Yes, there is with [**`bin2hex`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php)

Comment: where does $handle come from?

Comment: Regular expression should be enclosed with one character at both sides (like most common `/`) not the pair of braces. `{}` also  have a special meaning in regexp so it should (or could not) be used.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: preg_match is a PCRE-function, it's legal there : http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch04_10.htm

Comment: @Dr.Molle: $handle is my variable containing my file data. I used file_get_contents like so; $handle = file_get_contents($file_path); where $file_path is the location of my file. It's not how I actually handle my file data in my script, but it was a quick and simple way for me to test my regular expression.

Comment: And the file loaded via file_get_contents is Latin9-encoded too?

Comment: @Dr.Molle: The file is, yes. Dreamweaver's default encoding is set to UTF-8. So I would assume by extension then that my PHP file is also encoded in UTF-8, while my file is encoded in Latin9/iso-8859-15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always transform the letter:

```
$string = '£100.00';
if(preg_match("/\xa3/",$string)){
    echo 'match found';
}else{
    echo 'no matches';
}
```

Comment: That's truly strange. Why does that work, then? It's finding a match. Which is great, as my regular expression now works with this, but I don't understand why I can match this, and not the £ that's there in my string.

Comment: It could have something to do with the encoding.. I'm not sure, but if you transform it to a hexadecimal, then it searches regardless of the encoding.

Comment: I'll remember that in future. It's strange though. It must have to do with the encoding then. Anyway. This does solve my problem, although I wish I completely understood what's going on with my data to cause this.

Comment: If you do find out why, then please share.

Comment: The only possible reason I can think of right now is that the data was actually written on a foreign keyboard. The data actually originates from another country and I believe was subsequently translated into english. I don't know if entering a £ symbol from a foreign keyboard will actually mean it has a different character mapping or encoding, but if it does, this seems like the likely culprit.

Comment: I couldin't get `'/\xa3/'` or `'/£/'` to work until using `'/£/u'` The '/regexp/u' causes pattern strings to be treated as UTF-8 according to reference [link](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch04_10.htm) Im using PHP7.2.9 with html5 charset="utf-8"

Answer (score 2):

You can include any character in your regular expression if you know the hexadecimal value. I think the value is 0A3H, so try this:

```
 \xa3  // Updated with the correct hex value
```

Comment: @Samuel Yes, I left the upper case like in assembler. It is corrected.